# How to handle React props correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, kendo-grid, react-props

I posted this here because I am relatively new to React and didn't know what exactly should I google. In my React project, I have a kendo grid that has a custom column named OPTIONS, like this:

```
 <Grid onDataStateChange={onDataStateChange}
            data={result}
            {...{skip:0, take:13}}>
            <GridColumn cell={CommandCell} title="Options"/>
            <GridColumn field="session_id" title="Session" filter='text'/>
            <GridColumn field="sn_zag_id" title="Service" filter='text'/>
```

The Option column is defined like this:

```
const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false);
const [snZagId, setSnZagId] = useState();

const toggleDialogPrilog = (props) => {
    setVisible2(!visible2);
    setSnZagId(props.dataItem.sn_zag_id)
  }

const CommandCell = (props) => <Options {...props}/>

const Options= (props) => {
  return <td className="k-command-cell">
  <div style={{marginTop:'2%'}}>
       <Button style={{width:'8vw',marginTop:'2%'}}
        onClick={()=>toggleDialogPrilog(props)}>
        Add
        </Button></>}
  </div>
  { visible2 && 
       <Dialog onClose={()=> toggleDialogPrilog()} title={"Add"} style={{width:'50%'}}>
    <Prilog snZagId={snZagId}/>
    </Dialog>
  }
  </td>;}
```

So, In the option column I have a button ADD that, when it's clicked, opens a Dialog with PRILOG component inside it. The grid that I am talking about is big, made up of pages of 13 rows. Everything works perfectly, so when I click on the Add button, the dialog is open with custom material for that row. But the thing is, if I open the console/inspect, I can see that when I click add, 13 dialogs are open at the same time:

[image: Inspector]

I am aware to some point that when I click Add, all dialogs are rendered bcz I send props, but I don't know how to stop it. In other words, how can I modify my code so that only one(1) dialog opens when I click Add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem somehow, but I don't know what exactly is the difference. Instead of putting the Options component in the same jsx file, I made another component named SessionOptions like this:

Session.jsx:

```
import SessionOptions from '../../Popup/SesijaOpcije';
...
const CommandCell = (props) => <SessionOptions props={props}/>;
...
```

SessionOptions.jsx:

```
...
export default  function SessionOptions({props}) {
...
  return <td className="k-command-cell">
  <div style={{marginTop:'2%'}}>
       <Button style={{width:'8vw',marginTop:'2%'}}
        onClick={()=>toggleDialogPrilog(props)}>
        Add
        </Button></>}
  </div>
  { visible2 && 
       <Dialog onClose={()=> toggleDialogPrilog()} title={"Add"} style={{width:'50%'}}>
    <Prilog snZagId={snZagId}/>
    </Dialog>
  }
  </td>;}
```

And now it opens just one dialog. The only difference that I clearly see is in sending the props

```
//Before:
const CommandCell = (props) => <Options {...props}/>

//After:
const CommandCell = (props) => <SessionOptions props={props}/>;
```

The first one is property spread notation, and the second one is...? Can anybody explain the difference.
If anybody could clearify more.

Comment: You need to use `props={props}` now because you declared the component with `function SessionOptions({props})`. If you declared it with `SessionOptions(props)` then you would be able to use it the first way. The one with {} assumes the properties are an object with a property "props".

Comment: You can learn more about this syntax here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment (search for `function userId({id}) {`)

Comment: It is the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). If your object `test` is `{foo: 123, bar: 456}`, then the `{...test}` will act as if you manually wrote `foo={test.foo} bar={test.bar}` 
EDIT: oh you deleted your comment

Comment: @Nicofisi yes, I wrote it and only then saw your comment, thanks!